# MariaDB Query Construction

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This query works. But is there are better way to constructed it? I thought INNER Joins might be used. But I don't think I require them.

```
SELECT site.Name, vuln.Risk 
from site, vuln, system 
WHERE vuln.sysID=system.ID AND system.siteID=site.ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can use `JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.name, v.risk
FROM site s JOIN system sys ON s.id = sys.siteID
JOIN vuln v ON v.sysID = s.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks!! IDK Why I was having issues understanding JOINS

Answer (score 1):

You can use explicit join sintax  (work in the same way but is more clear)

```
SELECT 
      site.Name
    , vuln.Risk 
FROM site
INNER JOIN system on system.siteID=site.ID
INNER JOIN vuln on  vuln.sysID=system.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks!! IDK Why I was having issues understanding JOINS

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely recommend using explicit join syntax as they modern and clear.

```
select site.name,
    vuln.Risk
from site
join system on vuln.sysID = system.ID
join vuln on system.siteID = site.ID
```

Comment: Thanks!! IDK Why I was having issues understanding JOINS